# proof by maths induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, induction

not sure how to prove this:
for all positive intergers prove:
\begin{equation}
1+2(2)+3(2^2)+...+n(2^{n-1})=(n-1)(2^n)+1
\end{equation}
heres my try: 
prove $n=1$ : 
\begin{equation}
1=1
\end{equation}
assume true for $n=k$:
\begin{equation}
1+2(2)+3(2^2)+...+k(2^{k-1})=(k-1)(2^k)+1
\end{equation}
prove for
\begin{equation}
1+2(2)+3(2^2)+...+k(2^{k-1})+(k+1)(2^{k+1-1})=(k+1-1)(2^k+1)+1
\end{equation}
therefore:
\begin{equation}
(k-1)(2^k)+1+(k+1)(2^{k+1-1})=(k+1-1)(2^{k+1})+1
\end{equation}stuck from there onwards maybe understanding this wrongly.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please use LaTeX or writing mathematical formulas. I will edit your post so that you'll see how it's done.

Comment: You probably want the last term in the first sum to be $n(2^{n-1})$ to maintain the pattern of the previous terms.

Comment: yes supposed to be n(2 to the power of n-1) without -1 after it new to this so i dont know how to type it properly

Comment: You could use parentheses.  In your original text it showed 2^n-1 instead of 2^(n-1) and Andrew Thompson followed it.  You could use $\LaTeX$.  A primer is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  It takes some practice, but the results are nice.

Comment: Reformatted as written, but I might have slipped up (or there are some mistakes in the exponents). Please check.

Comment: i've corrected it the way i have it, is what i was doing correct towards the end?

Comment: What you have after therefore is exactly what you want to prove.  I think you need some details, which is exactly what I was doing in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n i2^{i-1}$  Your hypothesis is that $S(n)=(n-1)2^n+1$  As you say, it works for $n=1$.  Now assume it is true for $k$ and evaluate $$S(k+1)=S(k)+(k+1)2^k\\=(k-1)2^k+1+(k+1)2^k\\=2k2^k-2^k+1+2^k\\=[(k+1)-1]2^{k+1}+1$$

Comment: i see you have proven it but i don't see what you get (k+1)2^k

Comment: That is the term added to go from $S(k)$ to $S(k+1)$.  All the rest of the terms in $S(k+1)$ are already part of $S(k)$

Comment: i see where its coming from! can you explain the part after that in just a few more steps, sorry about that, your help is much appreciated though.

Comment: is it like 2^k[2k+1-1]+1, is so where would i get the next step

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Which line are you asking about?  For line 2, I put in the induction hypothesis.  The next two lines were using the distributive property.

Comment: the 3rd line 2k2^{k}-2^{k}+1+2^{k}, don't understand how it got to the next line :/

Comment: The first 2 was used to boost the exponent on the 2^k.  I added  and subtracted 1 from the k to make it look like what we want.  The other 2^k's cancel and leave the +1

Comment: i understand it now, thanks a lot.

Comment: one last questions, in line 2 isn't (k-1)2^k equal k2^k not 2k2^k?

Comment: nevermind i see where you get it, sorry mate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the $n^\text{th}$ term is $n2^{n-1}$, after verifying the initial case, you've just got to show that
$$
\overbrace{(n-1)2^n+1}^{\text{sum for $n$ terms}}+\overbrace{(n+1)2^n}^{\text{term $n+1$}}=\overbrace{n2^{n+1}+1}^{\text{sum for $n+1$ terms}}
$$